# Chrome margin differs from ie and ff

Tags: css, margins

Everything looks fine on firefox and ie, but chrome shows the menu about twice lower.
Live link here
http://soloveich.com/project2/

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12" id="desc">
<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>
</div>
</div>


<div class="row">
             <div class="col-lg-12" id="mn">
                <ul>
<li><?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu'  ) ); ?></li>
</ul>
             </div> 
</div>
```

css

```
#desc {
margin-top: 15px;
text-align: center;
}

#mn {
margin-top: 15px;
padding-bottom: -5px;
text-align: center;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 2px;
}
#mn ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#mn ul li {
display: inline;
text-align: center;
padding-right: 5px;
}
```

How do i fix that?

Comment: Why are you using a ul > li to display a div with another ul that contains several li elements? I would get rid of the first ul and li that you have in your code. In chrome, that lone li element is on its own line which is creating some issues.

Comment: I guess that ul li is embeded in WP. Still learning by trial and error method. That helped. tnx!

Comment: No problem. Most, if not all, WP themes will spit out the menu using a ul and li, so there's no need to put them in yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `ul` with the single `li` to a `div` and things settle down a bit.

It's not good practice to use lists when you don't need them. For one thing, it makes for needlessly messy code. For another, it makes page navigation strange for screen-reader users.

That said, I'm not sure why Chrome puts the single `li` and the child `div` on separate lines. You can probably get that fixed by fiddling with display states.